# Is it incorrect to refer to a set of things by using the singular form of the objects it contains?

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

I'm sorry I couldn't word that better, the following example will hopefully clarify:

[image: sample picture]

As you can see, the teacher refered to the bank of words as "word bank", as opposed to "words bank". Which one is correct? If "words bank" is the only correct usage then wouldn't it be fair to say that the exercise was resolved perfectly?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: the teacher used "word bank" instead of "words bank", is any of those incorrect in this context?

Comment: Bank is not “a words”, so “words bank” is wrong. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: because its a bank of words, not a bank of word

Comment: You seem to be making a use–mention error.

Comment: I misread that phrase as “word bank” (analogous to “coin bank”) instead of “the word _bank._” Perhaps that's what the questioner was thinking? Although you wouldn't write “coins bank” either. [Oh wait, it was the student who misread it, not me!]

Comment: Modifiers, whether noun or adjective, do not take plurals. Only head nouns take plurals. Thus, even though almost all customers will purchase two shoes at a time, the name of the store they buy them at is not a _*Shoes Store_, but rather a _Shoe Store_ (Except in Penang, where I have seen a _Shoes Store_ sign).

Comment: Mr D, That comment above from John Lawler has the answer. Respond to it, and for all similar questions in future, try ELL ell.stackexchange.com which is the Q&A site for English Language Learners. HTH.

Comment: John is right on the money, of course, but this question has been asked, and answered, a hundred times before. And I am not even exaggerating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually asking two questions here, and 'No' is the answer to each of them.  A *bank containing words* is properly referred to as a *word bank* not a **words bank*, just as a place to park cars is a *car park* not a **cars park*. What Emma appears to have ignored is the difference between using the word *bank* and mentioning it. If the exercise had said "use the word 'bank'"or "use the word *bank*" (which is the normal usage here), she would have been correct; but as it is 0/7 is the right mark.

Comment: "If the exercise had said "use the word 'bank'"or "use the word bank" (which is the normal usage here)" You meant instead of?

Comment: @MrD: No, you have missed the italics. Emma's mistake can be forgiven; yours, not so much.